# Notifications get UNREAD too early...(?)

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Do all notifications lose their UNREAD status right after you click on
 [image]?

If so, wouldn't it be better, when they turn to UNREAD, when one clicks on the corresponding notification itself?

One might miss notifications because they get UNREAD before you really read them...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it would not be better. I'll take the slight chance of overlooking  a notification over having to click on every "Thanks, got it" comment to mark it read. The `responses` tab  of  the user profile serves as a back-up of the notification box.

Comment: Oh Ok, I forgot the `responses`. That works...